# What is it called when using 'you' in place of anyone or yourself in example?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, adjectives

What is the adjective (or phrase) describing the use of 'you' in place of anyone, everyone, or yourself in passing?

Such as the following -

*...and **you** wouldn't dare to eat the last cookie, especially if it were macadamia nut, as this has been the boss's favorite cookie*

In the above, the speaker could be on a rant insinuating **she** would have enjoyed that last macadamia nut cookie, however decided against eating it as it is common knowledge that the boss would be interested in the very same cookie.

If the example were a failed quip, the speaker could combat the post-rant silence by exclaiming *I was being facetious!*, however in the above example the speaker would like to clarify the use of **you** by stating *I was being [blank]*

Any adjectives or phrases to describe the use of **you** in this situation?

Comment: It's called *third person indeterminate*.

Comment: Before asking on SE, you are required to make an effort to find the answer and show the background effort. This question is too elementary for ELU. Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/you

Answer (score 5):

It is called the *[generic you, indefinite you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)* or *impersonal you.*

*Wikipedia*